# Get current user on form load or workflow

Tags: sharepoint-online, infopath

I need information to be recorded with regards to who viewed the form to be recorded in a list. I an using SharePoint designer, infopath form and SharePoint online. I would appreciate a code less function if possible.

Answer (score 0):

Try this JS code

```
var clientContext = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
var website = clientContext.get_web();
currentUser = website.get_currentUser();
clientContext.load(website);
clientContext.load(currentUser);
   clientContext.executeQueryAsync(onRequestSucceeded, onRequestFailed);

function onRequestSucceeded() {
    alert(currentUser.LoginName);
}

function onRequestFailed(sender, args) {
    alert('Error: ' + args.get_message());
}
```

Comment: i am sorry, i am new to this can we wright code to an infopath form?. will there be any restriction on publishing it back to sharepoint online list?

Comment: @Monica Jagani your JS code make hem get Current user, I guess your code will not help to logging which user has been in the Infopath form